# Работа с большими числами, PHP

Tags: php

Не удается перевести строку в число при чтении файла.
Если делать `var_dump($line)`, показывает:

```
string(51) "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690
"
```

если перевожу в интеджер, то числа становятся:

```
int(9223372036854775807)
```

Как правильно сделать, чтобы строка "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690" стала числом 53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690?

Код программы:

```
<?php
  $sum = 0;
  $file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');

  if ($file) {
    while (($line = fgets ($file)) !== false) {
      $sum += (int) $line;
    }

    fclose($file);
    echo $sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
  function problem () {
    $file = file('file.txt');
    $sum = '0';
    $i = 100;
    while ($i >= 0) $sum = bcadd($sum, trim($file[$i--]));
 }
```

Comment: Гениально. )

Answer (score 1):

В php тип integer имеет ограничения от –2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647. )

Да и мне как-то сложно в принципе представить, где вам понадобилось такое большое число.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, по сути. Возможно, вам поможет [**Библиотека GMP**](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gmp.php).

Вот очень интересная статья на wiki.php.net: [**PHP RFC: Big Integer Support**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/bigint).

Answer (score 0):

А вот мне понадобилось такое большое число.
У нас в Казахстане у всех граждан индивидуальный идентификационный номер состоит из 12 цифр. Например, 900530300124.
И я бы хотел сделать на работе сервис, где все авторизуются, используя свой ИИН (вместо логина) и пароль.
И входящие POST данные на ИИН я хотел проверить через `(int)`.

Я сделал так:

```
$first = (int)substr($_POST["iin"], 0, 6);
$last = (int)substr($_POST["iin"], 6, 12);
$correct_iin = $first.$last;
```

Comment: А почему не использовать тип string, и не проверить регуляркой?

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = (int)substr($_POST["iin"], 0, 6);
$last = (int)substr($_POST["iin"], 6, 12);
$correct_iin = $first.$last;
```

Этот код может выдать не те значения на которые рассчитываем. К примеру, возьмём число 510231065412, при выходе получаем 51023165412. Из-за того что в переменной $last после вырезание строки во время преобразовании в int первое значение имеет 0.